# Unable to resolve module util from node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, node-uuid

There are some questions with this title but I have. tried every solution in them but I'm unable to resolve this.

I've just started learning React-Native and I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've tried the steps mentioned in this red box. I've tried deleting `node_modules` folder and then installing it again. I've also changed `"uuidv4": "^5.0.1"` version and installed `npm install` again. but it didn't work.  The code where I've used `uuidv4` is:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: uuid(), text: 'Milk' },
    { id: uuid(), text: 'Eggs' },
    { id: uuid(), text: 'Bread' },
    { id: uuid(), text: 'Juice' }
]);
```

I've imported it as `import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';`

Any help?

Comment: run `npm i uuidv4` it worked for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching for hours and hours this is how I solved the issue. The problem is not with `uuidv4` it's with `util`. All I did was to install `npm install util` and `uuidv4` is now working.

Here is the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/util of the package. Install this and it'll at least resolve this issue.

Comment: Did the `npm install util` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With `uuidv4@6.5.12` you can also:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

This gets rid of the utils dependency error without needing to install utils.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's been exported as default and you need to try this:

```
import uuid from "uuidv4";
```

Answer (score 0):

its not problem of `uuidv4`. uuidv4 use  `util` package most of time this package is not install. So Solution of this problem is that first install util package than install than install uuidv4.

Solution:

```
npm install util
```

than install

```
npm install uuidv4
```

Answer (score 0):

installing util package with the command `npm install util` resolved this issue for me.